# Replace elements in 2nd column of array with new value from 2nd column of smaller array when 1st column matches

Tags: python, numpy

I have two 2D arrays, e.g.,

```
A = [[1,0],[2,0],[3,0],[4,0]]

B = [[2,0.3],[4,0.1]]
```

Although the arrays are much larger, with A about 10x the size of B, and about 100,000 rows in A. I want to replace rows in A with the row in B whenever the 1st elements of the rows match, and leave the other rows in A unchanged.  In the above example, I want to end up with:

```
[[1,0],[2,0.3],[3,0],[4,0.1]]
```

How do I do this, preferably efficiently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will have to iterate through the entire array A once in any case, since we are transforming it. What we could speed up though, is the look-up if a particular first element of A exists in B. To that end, it would be efficient to create a dictionary out of B. That way, lookup will be constant time. I am assuming here that the first element of A matches to only one element of B.

Transforming B to a dict can be done this way:

```
transformed_B = { item[0]: item[1] for item in B}
```

Replacing the elements in A could then be done with:

```
transformed_A = [[item[0], transformed_B[item[0]]] if item[0] in transformed_B else item for item in A]
```

Comment: warunsl: This seems to return an array the size of B, rather than the larger A with some elements replace, Is there an "else" clause I should stick on the end, or a different replacement?  This is the line I used, based on yours, that results in the smaller array: yTest = [[item[0], lossesDict[item[0]]] for item in yTest if item[0] in lossesDict]

Comment: @ViennaMike You are right. It returns an array the size of B. You are also right that there should be an else clause. But the construct for the list comprehension changes a little. Instead of an `else` clause at the end, this is what you do: `transformed_A = [[item[0], transformed_B[item[0]]] if item[0] in transformed_B else item for item in A]`

Comment: warunsl: your original answer now edited to have your correction.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to sort the smallest array and use binary search to find matching values. You can do this in a vectorized manner as follows:

```
a = np.zeros((1000, 2))
b = np.zeros((100, 2))
a[:, 0] =np.random.randint(200, size=(1000,))
b[:, 0] = np.random.choice(np.arange(100), size=(100,), replace=False)
b[: ,1] = np.random.rand(100)

# sort and binary search
b_sort = b[np.argsort(b[:, 0])]
idx = np.searchsorted(b_sort[:, 0], a[:, 0])

# don't look at indices larger than largest possible in b_sort
mask = idx < b.shape[0]
# check whether the value at the returned index really is the same
mask[mask] &= b_sort[idx[mask], 0] == a[:, 0][mask]
# copy the second column for positions fulfilling both conditions
a[:, 1][mask] = b_sort[idx[mask] ,1]

# only values < 100 should have a second column != 0
>>> a
array([[  7.40000000e+01,   5.38114946e-01],
       [  8.80000000e+01,   9.21309165e-01],
       [  8.60000000e+01,   1.86336715e-01],
       ..., 
       [  1.88000000e+02,   0.00000000e+00],
       [  5.00000000e+00,   3.81152557e-01],
       [  1.38000000e+02,   0.00000000e+00]]
```

)

Comment: Jaime, Thanks! I selected warunsl's answer as the best to my particular question with two columns, but for a more general replace problem, I like your approach with masks, as I could see it being generalized.